# USD Export: unable to find suitable USD plugin to write

Tags: objects, export, add-on

When trying to export a mesh into a USD file it fails with this error in the log:

```
USD Export: unable to find suitable USD plugin to write <filepath>
```

This is with a fresh download of Blender 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. I downloaded the tar.xf file from blender.org, extracted, ran blender, made a mesh, tried to export to USD and I get this error.

Is there any additional configuration needed to export to USD?

Answer (score 1):

I think I just figured this out. I noticed I could export if I used the default file name and path. After experimenting, I think I can always export if I provide the extension in the export file dialog.

So, for instance if I click in the filename box and type "mytest" it will give me this error. If instead I type "mytest.usd", "mytest.usdc" or "mytest.usda" it exports successfully.

I guess I would have expected that when I didn't enter an extension it would export as "mytest.usd" and be a binary file. But, even if the current behavior is better, it might be nice to have a more intuitive error message. I thought my installation was broken when I first saw this.

Comment: Holy crap thank you! I'll report this as a bug.

Comment: nope, not working for me unfortunately.